# how to pass variable and array from jquery script to php file. And how to get the values that are passed in php

Tags: php, jquery

```
script file :
function addbooking()
{
    var id = localStorage.getItem("id");
    $.post("master/bookingdata.php",
        {
            id:id,
            newArray:JSON.stringify(newArray)

        }, function (data, status) 
    {
        document.location.reload();
    });
}

php file:
<?php
try
{
  $docsmart_id=$_POST['id'];
  $dataarray = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  $bookdate = $dataarray['date'];
  $Globalid = $dataarray['Globalid'];
}
catch(Exception $e)
  {`
      echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
  }

?>
```

-I am getting error undefined id.I m not able to get id and array which i have passed from script file.
-plus how to get data which is inside array.

Comment: Please read https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ and notice how to pass `data`.

Comment: @RohanSawant have you verified that the id is set in the localStorage and is actually being sent on the request?  `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['newArray']` should exist on the request.  Nothing about this request is sending json data in the body for you to parse out.

Comment: yess I have set the id.In console i have check ,i m getting the id. And how to get the array of objects which i have passed in php?

Comment: `json_decode($_POST['newArray'])`

Comment: thanks.One more help i need,@Taplar .how to get variables which is inside that array object

Comment: Once you parse it, it's just like any normal (associative) array in php.  Access it how you normally would.